# Running Ansible using slurm user: how can I fix ansible.legacy.setup failed to execute error?

Tags: ansible, slurm

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
task path: /opt/playbook/site.yml:1
Using module file /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ansible/modules/setup.py
Pipelining is enabled.
<localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: slurm
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'sudo -H -S -n  -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-mvloemssulwwmnnhtatxivyevcbshjsb ; /usr/bin/python3'"'"' && sleep 0'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {},
    "changed": false,
    "failed_modules": {
        "ansible.legacy.setup": {
            "failed": true,
            "module_stderr": "sudo: a password is required\n",
            "module_stdout": "",
            "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
            "rc": 1
        }
    },
    "msg": "The following modules failed to execute: ansible.legacy.setup\n"
}
```

A playbook is executed by the slurm user on node startup. However, it fails while gathering facts and I am unsure what the issue is. Apparently something is wrong with sudo. I am looking for ways to debug this more efficiently.

The playbook runs without issues under the regular ubuntu user.

## Simplified host File

```
vpn:
  children:
    master:
      hosts:
        localhost:
          ansible_connection: local
          ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
          ansible_user: ubuntu
          ip: localhost
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using `local` in my host file and therefore it was trying to run all scripts within the playbook on the master as the slurm user.

By changing `local` to `ssh` it now connects to the master as the ubuntu user and by that has no privilege issue later on.

Answer (score 0):

@natan -- I think it would probably be better if you didn't try to invoke `sudo` quite so directly. Also you probably don't need to be root just to execute `setup`.

Here's what the header looks like in a lot of my playbooks:

```
- name: Initial node setup
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:
  - name: Configure the machine...
```

Key things:

1. `hosts: localhost` -- this is the only machine you're working on.
2. `connection: local` -- avoids using `ssh` to connect to the machine it's already executing on anyway.
3. `gather_facts: yes` -- you can just get your `setup` facts using this and you shouldn't need to be root.

This still leaves the problem of how to become root for subsequent operations.
Traditionally, connection parameters (including passwords, if unavoidable) have been provided in the inventory file.
You can set the `ansible_become_password` in your inventory or in your playbook, but you should never have your password in plain text.
Then, for tasks that need to be root to succeed, you can use:

```
become: yes
```

I'd recommend this Ansible page for more info: [Ansible: Understanding privilege escalation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_privilege_escalation.html#become-connection-variables)

Comment: I think my issue is a different one. It worked with a very similar setup. I do need sudo for other parts and there is no occurrence of `gather_facts` in my entire project.

Comment: Ok, you don't have to use `gather_facts`, use can use `setup` as a task -- it essentially works the same way. I think the way you're trying to do what Ansible calls "privilege escalation" is kind of counter to how Ansible facilitates that. The page I linked to discusses all the supported methods of becoming root. If the `become_method` is "sudo" (default for Linux boxes) then Ansible is doing the `sudo` for you when it performs whatever task you need.

Comment: Also, you don't need to be root to run `setup`. If you're just trying to get the ansible_facts, you can do it as a non-privileged user. Additionally, it appears that `ansible.legacy.setup` is the same as `ansible.builtin.legacy`.